# Why moving this line cause deadlock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, thread-synchronization

I think I am missing something obvious here:

Why does this code doesn't cause deadlock:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object _lock1 = new object();
    object _lock2 = new object();

    Thread code1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (_lock1)
        {
            lock (_lock2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    });

    Thread code2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (_lock2)
        {
            lock (_lock1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    });

    code1.Start();
    code2.Start();

    code1.Join();
    code2.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

But this one does:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object _lock1 = new object();
    object _lock2 = new object();

    Thread code1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (_lock1)
        {
            lock (_lock2)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.WriteLine("A");
            }
        }
    });

    Thread code2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (_lock2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            lock (_lock1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B");
            }
        }
    });

    code1.Start();
    code2.Start();

    code1.Join();
    code2.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Comment: The behavior is undefined. Run a few times you may get different outputs.

Comment: http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/2008/0801/071201hs01/071201hs01.html ("The Problem: Anatomy of a Deadlock"). Why does your first example not _always_ fail? Only because you got lucky (as is often the nature of things with race conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code snippets can cause deadlocks and should be avoided.  It is just a coincidence, that first snippet didn't get into deadlock. Adding some operation between locks increases probability to get dead lock. 
For example, if you add Console.Writeline in between lock1 and lock2 it also increases probability of the deadlock.
You can run your first snippet in loop and receive a deadlock. For example, this code get into deadlock after a while:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                object _lock1 = new object();
                object _lock2 = new object();

                Thread code1 = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    lock (_lock1)
                    {
                        lock (_lock2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("A");
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                });

                Thread code2 = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    lock (_lock2)
                    {
                        lock (_lock1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("B");
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                });

                code1.Start();
                code2.Start();

                code1.Join();
                code2.Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Flow "assuming" Thread 1 executes first (this can actually still deadlock if t2 happens to catch l2 before t1):

```
t1 acquires l1
t1 acquires l2 //before t2..
t1 unlocks l2
t1 unlocks l1

t2 acquires l2
t2 sleeps
t2 acquires l1
t2 unlocks l1
t2 unlocks l2
```

If t2 "happens to run first"..

```
t2 acquires l2
t2 sleeps
t1 acquires l1 (while t2 is still sleeping)
t1 tries to acquire l2 but blocks.. it's already acquired by t2..
t2 is finished sleeping..
t2 tries to acquire l1 but blocks.. it's already acquired by t1..
```

IE: You can debug and see it print like:

```
Start T2
T2 - Locked L2
T2 - Sleeping
Start T1
T1 - Locked L1
```

-- DeadLock.. Neither can continue unless the other unlocks..

It's undefined behaviour. You also shouldn't be guessing which thread runs first.

Answer (score 0):

To help explain the "deadlock" question -

Use `Thread.Sleep` if you really want to suspend the thread.

But in this case where you don't want to suspend the thread, just suspend the 'task'.

Use some like this:

```
await Task.Delay(myDuration);
```

This will not suspend the entire thread, but just the single task you want to suspend.

All other tasks on the same thread can continue running...